# How to parse a large json file to round decimals to nearest integer and take average of y values if there is a duplicate in the x value?

Tags: python, json

I am interested in filtering and parsing through large json data such as below.
For the x values I would like to round to closest integer.

And if there are any duplicates I would like to take the average of the y values but keep the one entry of the x value.

For example below

original.json

```
{
  "DATA1": [
    {
      "x": 1.2,
      "y": 1.0,
      "z": null
    },
    {
      "x": 1.1,
      "y": 0.5,
      "z": null
    },
    {
      "x": 2.1,
      "y": 0.5,
      "z": null
    },
    {
      "x": 97.9,
      "y": 0.3,
      "z": null
    },
}
```

new.json

```
{
  "DATA1": [
    {
      "x": 1.0,
      "y": 0.75,
      "z": null
    },
    {
      "x": 2.0,
      "y": 0.5,
      "z": null
    },
    {
      "x": 98.0,
      "y": 0.3,
      "z": null
    },
}
```

Currently trying to implement a python function to process the json file but having a bit difficulty.

Comment: 1. If you're trying to do this in Python, why tag the question as Javascript? 2. Please add your code to the question so we can help you to debug it. SO is here to help you solve issues in code, not to write code for you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow below pseudocode:

```
Declare a HashMap, "x" as key and "y" as value

Declare new Array or List for "x" - uniqueX 
For each "x" in DATA1
    newX = rounded "x"
    If newX does not exist in uniqueX then
        Add newX in uniqueX

For each newX in uniqueX
    Declare new Array or List for "y" - arrY
    For each "x" in DATA1
        If rounded "x" is equal to newX
            Add "y" in arrY
    newY = average value of arrY
    Add newX and newY in HashMap

Form your new JSON using the HashMap
```

Once you've tried it, feel free to update your question with the code so that we can help you solve your issue as needed.